# SQL: Need formula to subtract one row from another under the same column

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Need assistance with creating a "Datediff"/"CASE" type of formula.

I have timestamps in the {incilog} table, in different rows across the same column {incilog.timestamp} that I need to subtract from one another, but only if the {incilog.transtype} equals "TR" from the row that has the {incilog.transtype} equal "FPS".

Logic is: If {incilog.transtype} equals "TR" and {incilog.transtype} equals "FPS", then subtract {incilog.timestamp} from {inciog.timestamp} in the corresponding row.

Basically, I need to get how many seconds it took from "TR" to "FPS".

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND ASSISTANCE!

**EXAMPLE OF DATA**

| timestamp | inci_id | transtype | descript |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/22/2022 12:14:46 AM | 2022264051 | TR | Time Received |
| 8/22/2022 12:17:00 AM | 2022264051 | FPS | Fire Pri. Started |

Comment: You will need to either do a window function or combine the rows into one using the inci_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a way to relate the two rows. Here, I assume that the two rows have the same `inci_id`.

You can relate different rows of the same table by selecting the same table twice and using a self-join. To do this you must give the two tables a different alias (here I used `a` and `b`).

```sql
SELECT
    a.inci_id,
    DATEDIFF(s, a.timestamp, b.timestamp) as diff
FROM
    incilog a
    INNER JOIN incilog b
        ON a.inci_id = b.inci_id
WHERE
    a.transtype = 'TR' AND
    b.transtype = 'FPS'
```

The first parameter of [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) indicates the unit used to express the difference.

See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41a5666c3aa7f95a32b7b6424ea06e0f